# Understanding Firefox 32 Garbage Collectioni

Tags: firefox, garbage-collection, spidermonkey

I have downloaded the Firefox 32 source code. I have read about the Generational Garbage Collection over here [1][2]. I have also gone through files like js/src/jsgc.h, js/src/jsgc.cpp, js/src/gc/zone.h, js/src/gc/heap.h, js/src/gc/marking.h etc. But I am unable to find in which file exactly the Generational GC Algorithm is implemented. In some places I find the GC code is written for Incremental GC and at some places I find for Generational GC using ifdef JSGC_GENERATIONAL. In which file do they have the code for Minor and Major collection? Even a quick walk-through will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

[1]https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/07/18/clawing-our-way-back-to-precision/
[2]https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Internals/Garbage_collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation details should be tracked in [bug 619558](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619558), you can see [the bug tree here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/showdependencytree.cgi?id=619558&hide_resolved=1)